# Non-human reviewer

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, community-user

In [this Low Quality Post review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1123214), the [Community user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) gave  **Looks OK** to the review target.  How can a non-human being review posts like real users?

Comment: I do not know the specifics of how the Community user works but this certainly seems like a problem that is well within reach of data science.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When a user account gets deleted, some of its actions (votes, reviews, etc.) sometimes move to the Community account so they will not be nullified (sometimes we *do* want these to be nullified, in which case the Community user is *not* assuming ownership on these actions).

Sometimes it's easy to just leave some traces of who was that user. But sometimes it's just not how things work.

I wouldn't worry about it. It just means that someone reviewed this, but then their account was removed for one reason or another.