# Review audit on my post. Reviewer is Community♦

Tags: support, review, review-audit, community-user

I looked at one of my old posts and saw that it was used in a review audit. [Here is a link to the audit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/556931) Rather than an actual person being the reviewer, it appears that the reviewer is Community♦. How does this happen?

Comment: I'd suspect the user that reviewed was deleted, but not sure.

Comment: You haven't really made it here, until one of your posts is used in a review audit. Congratulations, Matt!

Comment: Somewhat similar questions: [Non-human reviewer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29746) (on this meta) and [How can the Community user review a Low Quality post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284134) (on [meta.se]).

Comment: How do you find out that one of your posts was used in a review audit?

Comment: @GEdgar Look at one of your highly upvoted posts and check the timeline by clicking the clock on the left.

Comment: @GEdgar Example on one of your posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1633923/timeline

Comment: @MartinSleziak Those answer the question. This may even be a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-human reviewer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29746/non-human-reviewer) (I took your previous message as a suggestion to close as a duplicate. If I misunderstood, let me know and I can retract my vote to close.)